# Sizing headers to include arrows

Tags: coldfusion, resize, default, coldfusion-8

**How do I resize the columns in a grid to make enough space for the sort-direction arrows that appear when sorting by column?**

[image: Screenshot]

When my grid loads, it currently resizes the columns to fit the text of the columns precisely.  However, this does not leave enough room for the sort direction arrows that can appear, making them unable to be seen unless the column is manually resized.  **How can I set the default size of columns such that it includes space for these?**

Keep in mind that the column sizes must still be relative to the length of the header text; a completely fixed width is not sufficient.

Please be advised that I am new to both ColdFusion as well as the code base in which I am working in.  There may already be conflicting resizing functionality already being processed that I'm not aware of.  **Based on the way that the columns are already resizing, is there anything that the code may already be doing that I should be aware of?**

Comment: The best advise would be to NOT use `cfgrid` at all. It's poorly designed and not properly customizable. There are many better JS alternatives available. [You can start here.](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way)

Comment: @Alex Interesting!

Comment: I would agree with the previous comment about not using cfgrid.  It is built on an older version of extjs that hasn't been updated in awhile.  There are much better, maintainable, alternatives out there.

Comment: @DaveFerguson I like what I see regarding these alternatives.  Unfortunately, it's not really a viable option with this problem, as I'm trying to make a slight change to an existing codebase.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the (cfgrid) code that you are using?

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
<cfgridcolumn header="Something" name="Something" width="some number">.
```

Just make sure the number big enough.

Comment: I don't understand how this would be sufficient.  This would only set a column to an absolute number, while they still need to be partially relative.  i.e. they need to be the size of the header text plus some extra amount.  The width a column needs to be is unknown to the programmer.